# How to differentiate if the database as specified does not exist or the user does not have permission to access the database?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

Is there any option the specify the difference between existence and user access permission for a domino database in java?

from the isopen method https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ISOPEN_PROPERTY_JAVA.html I can not find a way to differentiate:

the database as specified does not exist; the user does not have permission to access the database

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that uses the [DbDirectory class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS_JAVA.html) to verify whether or not the filename of the database exists on the server, but that won't help you determine if the user doesn't even have access to the server, so it's probably not really giving you exactly what you want.